# How Resolution changes X & Y cords

Tags: delphi, math, pixel

I am tracking the color of a pixel at X & Y at a resolution of 1920 by 1080, I am simply wondering if there is any mathematically way to remain accurate in tracking the same pixel throughout various resolutions.
The pixel is not moving and is static, however I am aware that changing resolutions affects scaling and the X & Y system of the monitor.
So any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can you guarantee that in all resolution the same visible area of the screnn is covered? Or do you see black borders in some?

Comment: @yunnosch no black boarders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the whole screen area is filled, the same location on that physical screen (determined as the ratio of xLocation divided by the xWidth and the yLocation divided by the yHeight, this in centimeters or inches) will also always be at the same ratio of xPixelindex divided by xTotalpixels and yPixelindex divided by yTotalpixels.

Lets assume you have `xRefererence` and `yReference` of the target pixel, in a resolution `WidthReference` and `HeightReference` in which these coordinates mark the desired pixel.
Lets assume you have `WidthCurrent` and `HeightCurrent` of your screen size in pixels, for the resolurion in which you want to target a pixel at the same physical location.
Lets assume that you need to determine `xCurrent` and `yCurrent` as the coordinates for the pixel in the current resolution.

Then calculate the current coordinates as:

```
xCurrent = (1.0 * WidthCurrent) /  WidthReference * xReference;
yCurrent = (1.0 * HeightCurrent)/ HeightReference * yReference;
```

Comment: thanks for the response.

Would this method work across different monitors, Assume I am running a monitor with a max resolution of 1920 by 1080 - If another user were to run the program on a 4k screen (at 4k resolution ) would this formula still hold true? 

Or could the opposite be true, A user running the program on a monitor with the max resolution of 1600 by 1200.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "tracking the same pixel" AND "across different monitors"? How do you define "same pixel across different monitors"?

Comment: How is "A user running the program on a monitor with the max resolution of 1600 by 1200." the opposite of "run the program on a 4k screen"?

Comment: I have a program that needs the color information of a set pixel at X,Y Now on my current setup (1920 by 1080p) the program runs fine, correctly returning the color of set pixel. However I need a way to mathematically return the exact same pixel on various different setups IE where the monitor's width and monitor's height vary.

Comment: Please define "same pixel". Same coordinates is obviously not what you mean. You seem to not agree with "same fraction of X width and same fraction of Y height". Where is that same pixel? In which way do you specific the location? Centimeters from left and top screen edge? Do you have a sharpy mark on the glass/plastic of your display? How does that work when changing displays?

Comment: This might be one of the rare cases where it makes sense to show a picture of the screen you are looking at. Not a screenshot. Instead a smartphone camera picture of you pointing with your finger at the pixel you refer to. Several pictures actually, two in two different resolutions on your normal screen and another one of you pointing to a different screen.